# converting all typescript to javascript in the backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, backend, converters

I am a bit new to making Node JS production. I have written an app with typescript for the Node JS backend. Ar the moment in the package.json I am using the below in the script section :

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",.....
```

I know that in the production all the files need to be js for performance and I know I could use `ts something.ts somethin.js`  Of course I could write a script do to this for all the files but is there a simple way to just do this for me?

After changing that with tsc based on the people's comments I got the following errors :

```
src/index.ts:1:8 - error TS1259: Module '"c:/myProject/node_modules/@types/express/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag  1 import express from "express"; ~~~~~~~  node_modules/@types/express/index.d.ts:133:1 133 export = e; ~~~~~~~~~~~ This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.  src/index.ts:6:8 - error TS1259: Module '"path"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag  6 import path from "path"; ~~~~  node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/path.d.ts:178:5 178     export = path; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.  src/lib/data.ts:36:7 - error TS1056: Accessors are only available when targeting ECMAScript 5 and higher.  36   get taxYears() { ~~~~~~~~  src/lib/reader.ts:5:8 - error TS1192: Module '"fs/promises"' has no default export.  5 import fs from "fs/promises"; ~~  src/lib/reader.ts:6:8 - error TS1259: Module '"path"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag  6 import path from "path"; ~~~~  node_modules/@types/node/ts4.8/path.d.ts:178:5 178     export = path; ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ This module is declared with 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'esModuleInterop' flag.   Found 5 errors in 3 files.  Errors  Files 2  src/index.ts:1 1  src/lib/data.ts:36 2  src/lib/reader.ts:5
```

Comment: You can use a [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) ([ts-node docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node#via-tsconfigjson-recommended))

Comment: You do not use ts-node in production, It is mainly for dev. And as per the previous comment by @Reyno You can use a tsconfig. and then use the command as follows
```"start" : "tsc src/index.ts"```.   This is how you will do it. But Just make sure Typescript is installed in the production system

Comment: @SARANSURYA No, you don't need to have TS installed on the production system, because typically, you would build your package on some sort of development machine (or a dedicated build server) and not directly on the production system.. And typically you wouldn't call a build script `start` but something like `build`

Comment: Exactly, @derpirscher, I build all my TS files in a CI/CD cycle, so basically I just directly execute JS. But as per his question, this is what he should do.

Comment: Thank you guys but when I do tsc I got many errors regarding imports and exports. Is it possible for you guys show me the correct settings? thanks

Comment: Can you post the errors ?

Comment: I can post it as a new answer so I edited the post with the error

Answer (score 2):

ideally in production environment you won't use typescript at all, but instead build your typescript into javascript and then deploy only the javascript with your preferred system.
For this purpose you would use [tsc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) compiler.
You could use a script inside your package.json file like
`compile": "tsc --project {PATH_TO_YOUR_TSCONFIG_JSON_FILE}",`

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "declaration": true,
      "lib": [ "ES2022" ],
      "module": "CommonJS",
      "allowJs": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "noImplicitReturns": true,
      "outDir": "dist",
      "removeComments": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "strict": true,
      "target": "es2017",
    },
  }
```

And then, after the compilation produce the respective `js` file inside the specified `outDir` in your tsconfig.json file, you can simply execute your javascript file using node, or even have a specific script that would you the job for you

```json
"scripts": {
    "serve": "yarn build && node dist/src/index.js ",
    "lint": "eslint src --ext .ts",
    "compile": "tsc --project ./src/tsconfig.json",
    "build:clean": "rm -r ./dist && mkdir ./dist",
    "build": "yarn build:clean && yarn lint && yarn compile",
    "test": "ts-mocha --project test/tsconfig.json --require tsconfig-paths/register 'test/**/*.spec.ts' --exit --timeout 35000"
  }
```

`note`: You can define a basic `tsconfig.base.json` file in you root dir project and then create two or more separate `tsconfig.json` file inside for example your `src` and `test` folder that would extend the `tsconfig.base.json` file to specify different behaviours, but for this i advice you to read the documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html